# Numerical solution of a system of two exponential equations

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-value

I need to solve this two equations for x and y:

```
(sum ((i^2)e^(-x i - y i^2)), i = 1 to 6)/sum (e^(-x i - y i^2)), i = 1 to 6) = 12

(sum ((i)e^(-x i - y i^2)), i = 1 to 6)/sum (e^(-x i - y i^2)), i = 1 to 6) = 3
```

I've tried to use `NSolve` and find real solutions for `x` and `y`

```
NSolve[
  {Sum[k E^(k^2*(-y) - k x), {k, 1, 6}]/Sum[E^(k^2*(-y) - k x), {k, 1, 6}] == 3, 
   Sum[k^2*E^(k^2*(-y) - k x), {k, 1, 6}]/Sum[E^(k^2*(-y) - k*x), {k, 1, 6}] == 12}, {x, y}, Reals]
```

but I got the message:

> NSolve: Requested precision R is not a machine-sized real number between MinPrecision and MaxPrecision"

How do I proceed?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Could you add your code, which would help people find the problem?

Comment: NSolve[{Sum[k*E^(k^2*(-y) - k*x), {k, 1, 6}]}/{Sum[E^(k^2*(-y) - k*x), {k, 1, 6}]} == 3, {x, y}, 
  {Sum[k^2*E^(k^2*(-y) - k*x), {k, 1, 6}]}/{Sum[E^(k^2*(-y) - k*x), {k, 1, 6}]} == 12, {x, y}, Reals]

Answer (score 5):

A few problems with your code:

1. Curly braces `{}` can't be used as parentheses `()`.
2. You need a space or `*` between `k` and `x` to multiply them, otherwise Mathematica thinks it's a new variable `kx`.
3. The syntax of `NSolve` has a list of equations as the first argument, and a list of unknowns -- `{x,y}` here -- as the second argument.

The following seems to work:

```
NSolve[{
 Sum[k E^(k^2*(-y) - k x), {k, 1, 6}]/Sum[E^(k^2*(-y) - k x), {k, 1, 6}] == 3, 
 Sum[k^2*E^(k^2*(-y) - k x), {k, 1, 6}]/Sum[E^(k^2*(-y) - k*x), {k, 1, 6}] == 12},
 {x, y}, Reals]
(* {{x -> 0.440365, y -> -0.0399564}} *)
```